# Setting option SO_SETFIB on boost sockets

Tags: sockets, boost, boost-asio

I do not see any option to set SO_SETFIB on [boost sockets](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html).  Anyone has any idea or point me in right direction how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the `boost::asio::detail::socket_option::integer` socket option helper template:

```
typedef boost::asio::detail::socket_option::integer<SOL_SOCKET, SO_SETFIB> set_fib;

// ...
sock.set_option(set_fib(42));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I shall try that.  Can you please point me to any documentation? I gess instead of set socket option, I would need help in the direction of tcp::resolver

Comment: @BTRNaidu unfortunately the `set_option` interface (`SettableSocketOption` concept) is undocumented; you have to look at the header file to understand how to use it.

Comment: It did help.  Thanks.  But now I must set the socket option on resolver.  Do you have some code for that?

Comment: @BTRNaidu I'm not sure I follow - the resolver is a wrapper around `getaddrinfo`, which doesn't operate on a socket.

Comment: [SettableSocketOption](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SettableSocketOption.html) is documented.  I would be cautious directly using types in the `detail` namespace.  For this particular case, the `detail::socket_option::integer` models both GettableSocketOption and SettableSocketOption, and `SO_SETFIB` is a set-only socket option.

Comment: @TannerSansbury huh, so it is.

Comment: @ecatmur: the application running on a system which have multiple interfaces.  One of them is vpn.  I want the dns + http traffic to go through vpn interface only for this specific socket.  As dns in not related to the socket, any way to ask dns looks to be performed on a specific interface?

Comment: @BTRNaidu not using `getaddrinfo`. You'll need to use a low-level DNS library e.g. udns (http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/udns/udns.3.html).

Answer (score 3):

If Boost.Asio does not support a socket option, then one can create models of either [GettableSocketOption](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/GettableSocketOption.html) and/or [SettableSocketOption](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SettableSocketOption.html) type requirements to meet ones needs.

The  [`socket::set_option()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/set_option/overload1.html) accepts an object that models the SettableSocketOption type requirement.  The SettableSocketOption type requirement documents that models must provide a few functions that return values suitable to be passed to POSIX [`setsockopt()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/setsockopt.html):

```cpp
class option
{
  int level(Protocol) const;       // The 'level' argument.
  int name(Protocol) const;        // The 'name' argument.
  const int* data(Protocol) const  // The 'option_value' argument.
  std::size_t size(Protocol) const // The 'option_len' argument.
};
```

One can think of `socket.set_option(option)` as if it was:

```cpp
setsocketopt(socket.native_handle(), option.level(protocol),
             option.name(protocol), option.data(protocol),
             option.size(protocol));
```

The Protocol passed to the functions is a model of the [Protocol](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Protocol.html) type requirement.

---

Here is a `set_fib` class that is a model of SettableSocketOption:

```cpp
class set_fib
{
public:    
  // Construct option with specific value.
  explicit set_fib(int value)
    : value_(value)
  {}

  // Get the level of the socket option.
  template <typename Protocol>
  int level(const Protocol&) const { return SOL_SOCKET; }

  // Get the name of the socket option.
  template <typename Protocol>
  int name(const Protocol&) const { return SO_SETFIB; }

  // Get the address of the option value.
  template <typename Protocol>
  const int* data(const Protocol&) const { return &value_; }

  // Get the size of the option.
  template <typename Protocol>
  std::size_t size(const Protocol&) const { return sizeof(value_);  }

private:
  int value_;
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
// ...
set_fib option(42);
socket.set_option(option);
```